# Looking for ways to improve this code or if there is anything I shouldn't do

Tags: c

Trying to learn C so I made this short program to try and mimic classes. Is there anything with this code that I should not do with C or any ways that I can improve it at all like best practices or anything?

structs.h

```
struct weapon {
    char name[30];
    int damage;
    int durability;
};

struct player {
    int health;
    int armor_level;
    int currency;
    struct weapon player_weap;
};
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "structs.h"

struct player new_player();

void main() {

    struct player user = new_player();

    printf("The players health is %d.\n", user.health);
    printf("The players armor is %d.\n", user.armor_level);
    printf("The players currency is %d.\n", user.currency);
    printf("The players weapon is the %s.\n", user.player_weap.name);
    printf("The players weapon does %d damage and has %d durability.\n", user.player_weap.damage, user.player_weap.durability);

}

struct player new_player() {

    struct player new_player;
    new_player.health = 100;
    new_player.armor_level = 0;
    new_player.currency = 0;
    strcpy(new_player.player_weap.name, "Starter Sword");
    new_player.player_weap.damage = 1;
    new_player.player_weap.durability = 100;

    return new_player;

}
```

Comment: If you do not have a specific question and just want some comments on your code than it is better to use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I know you are not cramped for memory, but there is also something you could change about how structures are aligned in memory. structure padding and packing?

Answer (score 3):

Well there are few points:-
In case the structure is not too big you can do it in this way. *It is perfectly correct*.

`malloc` is computationally more costlier than copying variables on return from a function. In case the structure size is bigger then you should `malloc` it. That way you won't end up using a huge amount of memory in stack.

You should try to think of making the code reusable. You can keep a function which will print a structure. Something like (the same reason you kept a seperate function for getting an instance of struct).

```
void printPlayer(struct player p){
  ...
}
```

That way any time you try to print it - you would just call it. This saves you from repeating the same code of printing multiple times.

Another thing is, you can `typedef` the `struct player` to something more readable. In this case `player` is itself readable but in some cases `typedef` helps. But well that's [debatable](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/coding-style.html#typedefs).

Also the `main()` should be (the OS expects an integer back)

```
int main(void){
  ..
  return 0;
}
```

You can move the declaration of the function `printPlayer` or `new_player` to the header itself. That makes much more sense.

One another thing is using suitable names. `structs.h` is not a good name for a header file. In this project there won't be any `struct` header file? Keep the name `Player.h` or `Game.h`. That is much more readable.

Use header guards

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H 
#define PLAYER_H


struct weapon {
    char name[30];
    int damage;
    int durability;
};

struct player {
    int health;
    int armor_level;
    int currency;
    struct weapon player_weap;
};

#endif
```

Comment: What do you mean by moving the function declarations to the header?

Comment: @izzzi.: `struct player new_player();` this part you can keep in header.

Comment: The structs.h header file?

Comment: @izzzi.: Yes...

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of preference, but when I've used structs for things like that I've always done **`typedef`** to give myself a new data type. It makes writing the code easier, and helps me better comprehend what it is happening.

```
typedef struct {
    char name[30];
    int damage;
    int durability;
} Weapon;

typedef struct {
    int health;
    int armor_level;
    int currency;
    Weapon player_weap;
} Player;
```

So instead of declaring a function like

```
struct player new_player();
```

You would do it like this

```
Player new_player();
```

It simulates the process of working with classes much better, IMO. Also, whoever told you to use `void main()` is horribly out of touch. Don't ever use that unless you're writing a kernel or a microcontroller or something. It's **`int main(void)`** for pretty much every programming environment. Make sure you `return 0;` if your program has finished running successfully.

Comment: `return 0;` is also out of touch - since 1999, ending main with no return statement is equivalent to `return 0;`